# TaxonomyDAO is set to File System, which is not supported

Tags: tridion

I am running Tridion 2011 SP1 and am getting the following warnings in my cd_core.xxxx.xx.xx.log file.

```
2012-10-17 12:37:50,298 WARN  FSTaxonomyDAO - TaxonomyDAO is set to File System, which is not supported. Check your bindings settings and/or license file.
```

I have removed the following element from the cd_deployer_conf.xml

```
<Module Type="TaxonomyDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy"/>
```

but I am still getting warnings.

I think this problem is causing many of my multimedia components to fail when publishing. If fixing the cause of these warnings doesn't help then I'll have at least narrowed it down.

**edit**

I forgot to mention that I am using the File System as the Content Data Store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The storage bindings are in cd_storage_conf.xml. You need to check in storage config and should be storage to db. Also you should not remove from deployer if you are using taxonomy.

**Update**:

Taxonomy storage to file system bindings is not supported as far as I Know it can be only to DB, it is the same from release 2009 and What you are seeing is the WARNING message that you are using non supported. I am not sure if you can disable this binding.

Also, Metadata stored on the local file system is deprecated as of SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, in favor of storage of metadata in the database. SDL Doc reference [link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=File%2520System%2520storage%2520of%2520Metadata%2520is%2520deprecated.%2520&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1350482590518&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_CD_62F595D87FB747D9B7D370A00C529084&query=File%2520System%2520storage%2520of%2520Metadata%2520is%2520deprecated.%2520&scope=&filename=CDDepStatusFeatures.xml&docid=concept_CD_62F595D87FB747D9B7D370A00C529084&inner_id=&tid=4474dab4-eb72-4361-af76-2d0850644e38&addHistory=true&resource=).

Comment: I have edited my question to mention that I am using the File System as the Content Data Store

Comment: Updated the answer, taxonomy to file system binding is not supported.

Comment: Thanks. I do not need the Content Deployer to process any of the taxonomy information (categories/keywords). Ideally I would like to turn off the whole taxonomy functionality on the CD side and get rid of these warnings. If I don't get an another answer in the next few hours I'll have to assume that there's no way to turn off the Taxonomy functionality on the CD. (and I'll mark this as the answer)

Comment: If you don't specify any binding for Taxonomy it defaults to `ItemTypes` bindings at the root and even if that does not exist it defaults to `FileSystem`. I did not find any way to simply turn off. This is same for all item types like `Page` or `Component` etc.